# to create a tomcat server by terraform code

Tags: terraform

provider"aws" {
  access_key = "AKIAJ7STPAZVP4ZT74HQ"
  secret_key = "YRxdYqpOLDRCnPcKMBTL0dCSTFGILdd0brw2LlWq"
  region     = "us-east-1"
}
resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami           = "ami-0063927a"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.instance.id}"]
  tags = {
    Name = "main-example"
  }
 user_data = <<-EOF
              #!/bin/bash
                yum -y java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
                yum -y install tomcat
                systemctl enable tomcat
                systemctl start tomcat
                echo "

## welcome to tomcat,Hello World

" //etc/systemd/system/{{to                muser}}.service
                EOF

}
resource "aws_security_group" "instance" {
  name = "main-example-instance"
ingress {
    from_port   = 8080
    to_port     = 8080
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    ="-1"
    cidr_blocks =["0.0.0.0/0"]

}
}